# Generate SQL insert statements from JSON Object

Tags: sql, json

So I have a sql database which I know the schema to. What I want to do is have a model of that Entity/Table in json format, is there a library that will parse my JSON object and give me sql insert statements for that JSON?

For example, suppose I had

```
{
  Table:{
    id: 'abcd'
    name: 'Jim'
    apples: '5'
  }
}
```

Is there a library that would take that in and give me

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ('id', 'name', 'apples') VALUES ('abcd', 'Jim', '5');
```

Thank you in advance. IT's also fine if there's library for doing that but with format that can be translated into from JSON such as XML

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: A library in... ? Python? Java? .Net?

Comment: Javascript, I found this npm module called json-sql but it outputs it in this format 
insert into test (check1, check2, check3) values ($p1, $p2, $p3);
{ p1: 'check1', p2: 'check2', p3: 'check3' }

Which i recognize is php formatting, but is there a way to quickly make that recognized by sql?

Comment: I wanna insert my json object into dashdb or any other SQL database directly. Rather than having to prepare a query. Is there any javascript library that can help do that like spring data jpa in Java? Just wanna do - ```db.insert('MyTable', {name:'Adam', phone:'0576940', email:'test@test.com'});```

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be too hard to code yourself in java. Use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or some other json parsing library to parse the JSON. Iterate over each pair in the json and use [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to build a sql string.

Something like this to build the prepared statement:

```
    String query = "Insert Into Table1 (";
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPairs; i++) {
        query += "?, ";
    }
    query += ") Values (";
    for (int j = 0; j < numOfPairs; j++) {
        query += "?, ";
    }
    query += ")";
```

Then just iterate through each pair and set your values in the statement. Ensure your values are sanitized if from a user.

Note: This is really meant as some proof of concept and strings shouldn't be built this way. Use things like `StringBuilder` to build your prepared statement.

Comment: This is too much of a code for different types of SQL statements. Insert may be taken care of what about others?

I wanna insert/delete/modify my record from dashdb or any other SQL database directly using simple JavaScript function like JPA provides in Java, rather than having to prepare a query. Is there any javascript library that can help do that  Just wanna do - ```db.save('MyTable', {name:'Adam', phone:'0576940', email:'test@test.com'});``` or ```db.update('MyTable', {name:'Adam', phone:'0576940', email:'test@test.com'});``` or ```db.delete('MyTable', {name:'Adam'});```